# Popup Window After Print in vb 2019

Tags: vb.net, printing, popup, visual-studio-2019

Why when sending the print command a pop-up appears and the printing is not done until after pressing OK?

Is it possible to bypass this window (ie cancel its appearance permanently)?

[image]

Comment: How are you sending the print command? Can you post your code?

Comment: Thank you for contacting us
I found the cause of the problem
In the print code there was the command
MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString)
I did not notice him
Of course, with regard to the command to cancel the appearance of the page numbers window, it is
PrintDoc.PrintController = New System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController
It is listed for interest only

Answer (score 0):

The command to cancel the appearance of the page numbers window is

```
PrintDoc.PrintController = New System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController
```